# DataTable declaration inside SelectedIndexChanged method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, datatable, declaration

I am trying to define a `DataTable` inside a dropdownchange method as below :

```
protected void selectSegment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Segment' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + selectSegment.SelectedItem.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    DataTable dt = SPCommon.GetFilteredItems("Approvers Info", "Business_x0020_Unit", "ID", query);
}
```

---

> When i debug the above code, i get the error as `The name 'dt' does
>   not exist in the current context`

[image]
The same thing if i do on PageLoad, works fine :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {    
        DataTable Results = SPCommon.GetAllItems("Segments", "Title", "ID");
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem defalutListItem = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();
        defalutListItem.Text = "Select";
        defalutListItem.Value = "-99";
        Common.populateDropdown(selectSegment, Results, "Title", "ID", defalutListItem);
        Results.Clear();
    }
}
```

---

Please help understand why i am unable to declare a new DataTable variable inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` method?

Comment: Your code seems fine (atleast I cant find any error), are you showing everything? The only thing I would complain about is that you said ``"the same thing if I do on PageLoad, works fine."`` the 2 code parts dont really resemble at all.

Comment: Yes, there are no global declaration nor any other DataTable with same name. Let me post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something with you variable `dt`, because .net may have "optimized" it (remove it completly) because it's not used anywhere in your code. You can access it, even if it's not needed.